# Shouldn't operator[] and insert() functions behave the same way in a C++ map?

Tags: c++, dictionary, struct, insert, iterator

When I use operator[] to insert elements in a c++ map a bug occurs.

I have this map< Pair, int> variable. When I insert a new element into it, and then use a iterator to print its keys, some elements of the map randomly disappear as well as the values are not printed in increasing order. However, when I insert elements using funtion insert(), everything works fine. What am I doing wrong with operator[]? Should not the result be the same in both cases?

Remark: each key Pair is a struct storing a pair of ints.

Here is an example:
I insert the six following keys (5,9), (5,11), (5,12), (4,14), (1,10), (3,10).
Then, I iterate over the map and the key (3,10) disappears. Also, the elements are not printed in order.
To see the correct way they should be printed, just follow the instructions given in the code comments below.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

struct Pair {
    int a;
    int b;

    Pair(const int& a,const int& b) { //assures the first int is the smaller one
        if (a < b) {
            this->a = a;
            this->b = b;
        } else {
            this->b = a;
            this->a = b;
        }
    }

    bool operator<(const Pair& otherPair) const {
        return this->a < otherPair.a || this->b < otherPair.b;
    }
};

int main() {
    Pair elements []{ Pair (5,9), Pair (5,11), Pair (5,12), Pair (4,14), Pair (1,10), Pair (3,10) }; // keys to insert into the map

    map<Pair,int> mapPairInt; // map to store the elements

    for(int i = 0; i <6;i++){ 
        mapPairInt[elements[i]] = 0; //insert elements using operator[]
        //mapPairInt.insert ( std::pair<Pair,int>(elements[i],0) ); // insert elements using insert() -- uncomment this line and comment the line above. This will make everything works properly
}

    //print the keys stored by the map (the keys should be printed in increasing order)
    map<Pair,int>::iterator it = mapPairInt.begin();
    while(it != mapPairInt.end()){
        cout<< it->first.a << "-" << it->first.b <<endl;
        it++;
    }

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `Pair::operator<()` violates requirements of `std::map`, namely transitivity. For example, `(5,12) < (4,14)` but at the same time `(4,14) < (5,12)`. This must imply `(5,12) < (5,12)` which is false (and even if it was true, it would violate another requirement, irreflexivity).

This violation causes undefined behaviour, so anything can happen.

BTW the most compact way of writing correct comparison operator known to me is

```
bool operator< (const Pair& otherPair) const {
    return std::tie(a, b) < std::tie(otherPair.a, otherPair.b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bool operator<(const Pair& otherPair) const {
    if (this->a == otherPair.a)
    {
        return this->b < otherPair.b;
    }
    return this->a < otherPair.a;
}
```

Is what your comparator should look like. It produces the results you expect.